# Как добавить класс в javascript

Tags: javascript

**Там где button-podarok как добавить еще одинк класс?**
Надо просто дописать класс, помогите!

Например такой хочу вставить, **.red-btn** ,можно конечно два раза скрипт написать но это тупо очень, в бэк никогда не лезу но просто надо добавить класс и все(

*Чтобы срабатывал еще один класс кроме .button-podarok*

```
$(function() {
    $('a[rel=popup]').leanModal({closeButton:'.close-popup'});

$('.button-podarok').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  val = {};
  $('.error-input').removeClass('error-input');
  err = false;
  $(this).parent().parent().find('input').each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('type')=='radio') {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) val['type'] = $(this).val();
    }
    else {
      if ($(this).val()=='') {
        err = true;
        $(this).addClass('error-input');
      } else
        val[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

перечисляйте через запятую:

```
$('.button-podarok,.red-btn').click( ...
```

Comment: @Оля Милохина-Иванова, достаточно отметить ответ, как верный, нажав галку рядом с ответом. А "наградить", будете нажимать когда разбогатеете ;)

Comment: Благодарю! еще раз вроде нажала)